# How to cast a variable member to pass it as reference argument of a function

Tags: c++

When I try to compile some code very similar to this one with VC++2015 I get a:

**C2664 cannot convert parameter number 1 from 'unsigned int' to 'short &'**

```
class Foo
{
public:
    unsigned int A;
    unsigned int B;
}

void foo(short& a)
{
    a++;
}

void main()
{
    Foo f;
    foo(f.A);
}
```

What is the correct way to cast it?

Comment: That's not going to work.  A reference must always be a valid object and there is no valid way of making an unsigned int be a short by reference.

Comment: In my mind it would be better to rewrite *the function* to handle what you actually want to pass to it. Or add a function overload.

Comment: Sorry, its just an example, I have a working code that requires a cast, is it impossible?

Comment: Casting a variable that you pass by reference definitely falls into the realm of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Got it, I believe I can just overload the function

Comment: You could do this, but it likely wouldn't do what you really want: `foo(*(short*) &f.A);` especially on a big endian machine.

Comment: @jschultz410 that causes undefined behaviour by violating the strict-aliasing rule

Comment: @MattMcNabb I figured there would be a catch. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with a cast because `unsigned int` cannot be aliased as `short`. To call this `foo` without changing it, the code would be:

```
if ( f.A > SHRT_MAX )
    throw std::runtime_error("existing value out of range for short");

short sh = f.A;
foo(sh);
f.A = sh;
```

You may want to check `sh >= 0` before reassigning it to `f.A`; and `foo` should guard against integer overflow.

Comment: I ended up writing an overload. Great answer though